# is the time_taken_micros field in the GCS access log a signed 32 bit integer?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

because I have seen a negative value returned ;-)

also, since the GCS usage logs are written every hour, what happens if a request (eg to download a file) takes more than an hour?  how will that show up in the logs?

Comment: The log entry will show up in the hour that a request completes. Looking into negative time_taken_micros values...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time_taken_micros field is int64, but we have identified a bug in the intermediate math that could in certain cases lead to what you observed. A fix is pending and will hopefully roll out today. Thanks for the report!

As to your second question, the log entry will appear in the hour that the request completes.